# Unable to get specific type from IResourceDescription in xtext

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

I have added new parser rule in my existing xtext grammar and trying to refer the new rule from another parse rule.

For custom validation, I am trying to get the visible object of new rule using getExportedObjectsByType from IResourceDescription object.getExportedObjectsByType() is returning empty for new rule.getExportedObjectsByType() is working as expected for other rules. How to fix this problem. Am i missing anything in my grammar?

My new parse rule will look like below:

```
Test: 
 'ToTest''(' (members+=Member'[' members+=Member (',' members+=Member)*']') ')'
;

Member :
 '{' pairs+=Pair (',' pairs+=Pair)* '}'
;

Pair :
 name=STRING ':' value=Value

ExistingRule:
  (toTest=Test)?;
```

I am trying to refer the new rule ,Test, in already existing rule as a Ereference.

Comment: how does your rule look like? does the element have a explicit (grammar) or implicit (nameprovider) name

Comment: My new parser rule will look like this, Test: 
 'ToTest''(' (members+=Member
 | '[' members+=Member (',' members+=Member)* ']') ')'
;

Member :
 '{' pairs+=Pair (',' pairs+=Pair)* '}'
;

Pair :
 name=STRING ':' value=Value
; I am trying to refer the new rule ,Test, in already existing rule as a Ereference.

Comment: test has no name: what should be the name it is referred to

Comment: I have assumed that Test is the new parser rule and it's name is Test. I am trying to refer that in ExistingRule with the reference name of toTest. Am i doing anything wrong? but all other parser rule in my grammar also created same way and all are working fine.

Comment: then you need  name='ToTest' or adapt IQualifiedNameProvider

Comment: I did't get you,can you please provide one example? and explain why should we change in IQualifiedNameProvider ?

Comment: if a thing has no name it wont be in the index. so give it a name or calciulate one. e.g. https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/07/16/iqualifiednameproviders-in-xtext-2.0/

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance@ChristianDietrich